# django rest framework - get two models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have multiple models that are associated by Foreign Keys.  I can export them all separately using django rest framework on a one to one basis, and I can also export multiple ones nested.  However I want to be able to essentially "concatenate" them together into a single json/xml export.

The models in the example below are joined by a one to one foreign key on jobdtl_id.  I have some where it's one to many but I'm hoping I can figure that out when I know how to get a view that will link 2 separate models like I want below -

Here's an example of what I want the json to look like by hitting a single URL like

`http://localhost/job/4/`

```
{
  "job": {
    "-id": "9878",
    "-name": "This is the job",
    "-master": "blahserver",
    "-dbversion": "234",
    "-xmlversion": "1",
    "jobmst": {
      "jobmst_id": "9878",
      "jobmst_type": "2",
      "jobmst_prntid": "234",
      "jobmst_active": "Y",
      "jobmst_name": "This is the job",
      "jobmst_owner": "Owner",
      "jobdtl_id": "9878",
      "jobmst_lstchgtm": {
        "-date": "Y",
        "#text": "2013-10-23 09:22:08.0"
      },
      "jobmst_prntname": "Parent",
      "jobmst_alias": "9878"
    },
    "jobdtl": {
      "jobdtl_id": "9878",
      "jobdtl_cmd": "blah.exe",
      "jobdtl_failalarm": "NULL",
      "nodmst_id": "NULL",
      "nodlstmst_id": "NULL",
      "jobdtl_inhevent": "Y",
      "jobdtl_inhoptions": "Y",
      "jobdtl_inhagent": "Y",
      "jobdtl_inhrepeat": "Y",
      "jobdtl_inhtime": "Y",
      "jobdtl_timewin": "NULL",
      "jobdtl_saveoutput": "Y",
      "jobdtl_outputname": "NULL",
      "jobdtl_trackmethod": "1",
      "jobdtl_trackcmd": "NULL",
      "jobdtl_deplogic": "1",
      "jobdtl_rerun": "NULL",
      "jobdtl_params": "--blah --ok"
    },
    "jobdep": [
      {
        "jobdep_id": "79670",
        "jobmst_id": "9878",
        "jobdep_type": "1",
        "jobdep_jobmst": "another job",
        "varmst_id": "NULL"
      },
      {
        "-num": "2",
        "jobdep_id": "83783",
        "jobmst_id": "9878",
        "jobdep_type": "1",
        "jobdep_jobmst": "and another",
        "varmst_id": "NULL"
      }
    ],
    "trgjob": [
      {
        "trgjob_id": "22286",
        "trgmst_id": "23455",
        "jobmst_id": "9878"
      },
      {
        "-num": "2",
        "trgjob_id": "28980",
        "trgmst_id": "23521",
        "jobmst_id": "9878"
      },
      {
        "-num": "3",
        "trgjob_id": "28981",
        "trgmst_id": "9237",
        "jobmst_id": "9878"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The models are basically like this -

```
class Jobdtl(models.Model):
    jobdtl_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    jobdtl_cmd = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ....
    jobdtl_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobdtl'

class Jobmst(models.Model):
    jobmst_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    jobmst_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    ....
    jobdtl_id = models.ForeignKey('Jobdtl', db_column='jobdtl_id', related_name='mstdtl', blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jobmst_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobmst'
```

end caveat I'm converting the json from how the XML looks for the existing legacy app which is like so -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<job id="9878" name="This is the job" master="blahserver" dbversion="532" xmlversion="1">
    <jobmst>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
        <jobmst_type>2</jobmst_type>
        <jobmst_prntid>234</jobmst_prntid>
        <jobmst_active>Y</jobmst_active>
        <jobmst_name>This is the job</jobmst_name>
        <jobmst_owner>Owner</jobmst_owner>
        <jobdtl_id>9878</jobdtl_id>
        <jobmst_lstchgtm date="Y">2013-10-23 09:22:08.0</jobmst_lstchgtm>
        <jobmst_prntname>Parent</jobmst_prntname>
        <jobmst_alias>9878</jobmst_alias>
    </jobmst>
    <jobdtl>
        <jobdtl_id>9878</jobdtl_id>
        <jobdtl_cmd>blah.exe</jobdtl_cmd>
        <jobdtl_failalarm>NULL</jobdtl_failalarm>
        <nodmst_id>NULL</nodmst_id>
        <nodlstmst_id>NULL</nodlstmst_id>
        <jobdtl_inhevent>Y</jobdtl_inhevent>
        <jobdtl_inhoptions>Y</jobdtl_inhoptions>
        <jobdtl_inhagent>Y</jobdtl_inhagent>
        <jobdtl_inhrepeat>Y</jobdtl_inhrepeat>
        <jobdtl_inhtime>Y</jobdtl_inhtime>
        <jobdtl_timewin>NULL</jobdtl_timewin>
        <jobdtl_saveoutput>Y</jobdtl_saveoutput>
        <jobdtl_outputname>NULL</jobdtl_outputname>
        <jobdtl_trackmethod>1</jobdtl_trackmethod>
        <jobdtl_trackcmd>NULL</jobdtl_trackcmd>
        <jobdtl_deplogic>1</jobdtl_deplogic>
        <jobdtl_rerun>NULL</jobdtl_rerun>
        <jobdtl_params>--blah --ok</jobdtl_params>
    </jobdtl>
    <jobdep>
        <jobdep_id>79670</jobdep_id>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
        <jobdep_type>1</jobdep_type>
        <jobdep_jobmst>another job</jobdep_jobmst>
        <varmst_id>NULL</varmst_id>
    </jobdep>
    <jobdep num="2">
        <jobdep_id>83783</jobdep_id>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
        <jobdep_type>1</jobdep_type>
        <jobdep_jobmst>and another</jobdep_jobmst>
        <varmst_id>NULL</varmst_id>
    </jobdep>
    <trgjob>
        <trgjob_id>22286</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>23455</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
    </trgjob>
    <trgjob num="2">
        <trgjob_id>28980</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>23521</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
    </trgjob>
    <trgjob num="3">
        <trgjob_id>28981</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>9237</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>9878</jobmst_id>
    </trgjob>
</job>
```

Comment: Well that's not valid json, do you want an array of results? Or a parent object that lists the two models?  It's easy with a custom serializer as long a it's read only. Read/write compound serializers take someone work.

Comment: I updated the json so I hope it makes more sense.  Yes it would only have to be read only.

Comment: @whoisearth The number of opened/closed curly braces doesn't match, so it's hard to figure out what is the exact json structure, can you please correct this..

Comment: I've updated it to include a formatted json which I believe is correct.  I've also included the source XML which I want to base it off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by doing the following in my views.py

```
...
@csrf_exempt        
def tesxml_test(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        mst = Jobmst.objects.using('database1').get(jobmst_id=pk)
        dtl = Jobdtl.objects.using('database1').get(jobdtl_id=pk)
        dep = Jobdep.objects.using('database2').filter(jobmst_id=pk).order_by('jobdep_id')
        trg = Trgjob.objects.using('database1').filter(jobmst_id=pk).order_by('trgjob_order')
    except Jobmst.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #Get String Results of 4 queries
        jobmststring = JobmstSerializer(mst)
        jobdtlstring = JobdtlSerializer(dtl)
        jobdepstring = JobdepSerializer(dep)
        trgjobstring = TrgjobSerializer(trg)
        #Get serialized Results of 4 queries
        jobmst_serialized = {'jobmst': jobmststring.data}
        jobdtl_serialized = {'jobdtl': jobdtlstring.data}
        jobdep_serialized = {'jobdep': jobdepstring.data}
        trgjob_serialized = {'trgjob': trgjobstring.data}

        jobgroup = jobmst_serialized, jobdtl_serialized, jobdep_serialized, trgjob_serialized,


        jobgroupresponse = TESXMLResponse(jobgroup)
        return jobgroupresponse
...
```

It's not perfect but it puts me on the next step of my problem which is customizing the renderer to get the data in the root fields which I have another SO question for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MSTSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    jobdtl_id = DTLSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Jobmst
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'jobdtl_id'...)

class DTLSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Jobdtl
        fields = ('id', 'url',  ...)
```

Would result in a more correct data structure of

```
{
    "jobmst_id": 4,
    "jobmst_type": 1,
    "jobdtl_id": {
       "jobdtl_id": 4,
       "jobdtl_cmd": null,
       "jobdtl_duration": 1379
    },

}
```

Comment: Yup this is what I'm currently doing but it contains 2 problems.

Comment: Yup this is what I'm currently doing but it contains 2 problems.
1.  it creates a heirarchy which I don't necessarily want by linking the jobdtl_id to the next model.
2.  some the order of foreignkey isn't always in the same direction.  Ideally I want to be able to punch in http://localhost/job/4/ and get all the associated tables I have with the jobmst_id column.  Some tables may return multiple values and some none but in the end I want it all displayed like my initial question which is basically concatenating the separate json all together into 1.